# Joomla frontpage component template parameter switch

Tags: php, if-statement, joomla, joomla3.0

Using Joomla 3.1 & creating a template.

I have a template parameter switch to show the frontpage 'component' or hide it.

I am using the following in my index.php file at present:

```
<?php
$menu = & JSite::getMenu();
if($menu->getActive() !== $menu->getDefault()) : 
?>
<jdoc:include type="component" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

I want to add a `<?php if ($frontpageshow) : ?>` statement to the above, so that the following scenario's happen:

1. If my template parameter is set to "show frontpage component" - `<jdoc:include type="component" />` is shown on the frontpage & all pages.
2. If If my template parameter is set to "hide frontpage component" - `<jdoc:include type="component" />` is **not shown** on the frontpage, but **is shown** on all other pages.

Any idea's?

My templateDetails.xml is as follows:

```
<field name="frontpageshow" type="radio" class="btn-group" default="1" label="TPL_FRONTPAGESHOW_LABEL" description="TPL_JOOSTRAP_DESC">
   <option value="1">JYES</option>
   <option value="0">JNO</option>
</field>
```

I have another file declaring my variables, i.e.

```
$frontpageshow = $this->params->get('frontpageshow');
```

Comment: Can you add your templates XML?

Comment: templateDetails.xml for the "frontpageshow" field added to above post.

Comment: i also have a another file with my variables in like this $frontpageshow = $this->params->get('frontpageshow'); but happy for this to go into the top of my index.php file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<?php
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu();

if ($frontpageshow){ 
    // show on all pages
    ?><jdoc:include type="component" /><?php 
}
else {
    if ($menu->getActive() !== $menu->getDefault()) {
        // show on all pages but the default page
        ?><jdoc:include type="component" /><?php
    } 
}
?>
```

Hope this helps